# HTML AngularJS - select binding

Tags: html, angularjs

I got a form which is auto-filled when you a select a name.

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="user as user.name for user in users" >
</select>
```

So when I select my user, the next field (address, email, phone, ...) will be filled with the data of the selected user.

```
<input type="text" id="address" value="{{selected.address}}">
```

My problem is that I've a select with all the country and I want to get the selected country display.

```
<select class="form-control">
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>.....
```

So when I select "Marc" who's living in United-States, I want the select country to display "United states" instead of the first option "Afghanistan".

Hope my problem is clear enough.

Thx !

Comment: use ng-options and ng-model on country select too like `ng-model="user.country_code" ng-options="c.code as c.name for c in countries"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `ng-selected` directive.

Suppose your selected person has a `country` property which has the country code and that you have an array of country objects `{code: 'AF', name: 'Afganistan'}` etc

```
<select ng-model="selected.country" >
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" 
            value="{{country.code}}" 
            ng-selected="country == selected.country">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kevisiv/1/edit?html,js,output)**

```
 <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="user as user.name for user in users" >
</select>

  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.country">
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>

  </select>
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module("SO29142872", [])
  .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.users = [{
      "name" : "Mohamed RIas",
      "country" : "AX"
    },{
      "name" : "Weedoze",
      "country" : "AL"
    }]

});
```